# IEx.pry on windows won't run because erlang console closes to soon

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to debug elixir code in phoenix application using

```
IEx.pry
```

but after running this line inside cmder console

```
iex.bat --werl -S mix phoenix.server
```

erlang console opens and closes. I don't have enough time to see if there is anything written out. Is there a way to hold erlang console open or to debug elixir code in some other way?

Comment: What do you get if you try that from a normal cmd console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `iex.bat --werl -S mix phoenix.server` command in a [cmd](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) console (as opposed to running it in cmder).